# PHP include problem, not sure what the problem is

Tags: php

```
<?php
$city = $_GET["city"];
$prov = $_GET["prov"];

$file = "citycountdetails.php?city=".$city."&prov=".$prov."";
?>

<?php include $file; ?>
```

Warning: include(citycountdetails.php?city=Halifax&prov=NS) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ....

Not sure what I am doing wrong...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot include a file with parameters in there I'm afraid!

Those parameters are only for http requests. php includes do not launch http requests, they just include local files from the file system.

There are several ways to achieve what you're trying to do:

---

access $_GET["city"] and $_GET["prov"] from within citycountdetails.php.

This is the quick ugly method,and leads to quite a bit of dependency, but its not bad at least.

---

declare $city and $prov, and access it from citycountdetails.php (using globals).

This is probably the worst way to do it, so don't do this. :D

---

create a functions file with methods to retrieve those parameters

Probably the easiest thing you can do now, without all the bad side effects.

functions.php

```
<?php 
function GetCity(){
   return $_GET['city'];
}
function GetProvince(){
   return $_GET['prov'];
}
?>
```

Your file

```
<?php
include 'functions.php';
include 'citycountdetails.php';
?>
```

city count details.php

```
<?php
$city = GetCity();
$prov = GetProvince();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to include a file with query string parameters, as PHP will interpret the query string as part of the filename.  If you need to pass `$city` and `$prov` into `citycountdetails.php`, they are already available in the global scope.

Modify `citycountdetails.php` to reference `$city` and `$prov` as `$GLOBALS['city']` and `$GLOBALS['prov']` instead of `$_GET['city']` `$_GET['prov']`.

```
// citycountdetails.php
<?php
$city = $GLOBALS['city'];
$prov = $GLOBALS['prov'];
?>

// Or similarly accomplished in functions.php
<?php 
function GetCity(){
   return $GLOBALS['city'];
}
function GetProvince(){
   return $GLOBALS['prov'];
}
?>
```